# Bone rotating around cursor instead of origin

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I'm new to blender, trying to animate the fingers of a character. The finger bones are parented (not connected), but they are rotating around the cursor, instead of their origin. How can I make these finger bones rotate around the their origin? Seems really simple, but I'm struggling to figure out why they are behaving like this.

Also, this rigged model is a paid asset from the Unity asset store. I did not make it, maybe there's something fishy going on from the import to Blender?

[image: Image0]
[image: Image1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push . (Period, not on the numpad) to switch transform pivot modes. You can also do it the slow way by clicking up here:

[image]